# Android TextView showing memory reference

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have one text view in my android application that seems to be showing some kind of memory reference instead of the string resource that I had set it to show. It looks the same as what happens when you try and print an array with the default toString in java. Any help trying to spot whats wrong would be a great help. I'll post the code snippets below:

XML Layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/summary_name_heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/secondary"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

String resource

```
  <string name="summary_name_heading_text">Song : </string>
```

Code

```
TextView nameHeading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summary_name_heading);
nameHeading.setText(R.string.summary_name_heading_text);
```

This is what it shows on screen:

android.widget.TextView@417e0528

Comment: paste the code snippet where you're trying to display the text of your `TextView`.

Comment: Those are the code snippets I'm just populating this text view with a string from the resources folder I have no android code dealing with the headings.

Comment: check my answer. Try doing that and it should **display** what you want.

Comment: @peppermcknight try cleaning your project and either change the string name or the TextView id so they're not the same. This is how I'd start debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass to the setText method of your `TextView` the string you want to show. If you pass an instance of a `TextView`, the `toString()`'s method of the `TextView` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing in your activity, but this is how you get the data from your `TextView`.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summary_name_heading);
String myText = tv.getText();
```

`myText` now has the text you want.

**Update:-**

Setting `String` in your activity.

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.summary_name_heading_string);
tv.setText(mystring);
```

But nevertheless, as **A-C** suggested, try to clean your project and change either the String name and `Id` of your `TextView`.

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the text from this textview because I have defined it myself in strings.xml my problem is that instead of displaying this string it displays the stuff shown above